# Math: get index in js

Tags: javascript, math

i have `javascript, angularjs` and array of values. `values.length%3 = 0` always

if `values.length == 6` - i have index : `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`

there is a mathematical solution to get the following -

```
if 0, 1, 2 - get 0
if 3, 4, 5 - get 1
```

also i can be dynamical:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
```

then need to get

```
if 0, 1, 2 - get 0
if 3, 4, 5 - get 1
if 6, 7, 8 - get 2
```

Comment: Your question is missing the issue description.

Comment: I don't understand `if 0, 1, 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, what you want is what "range" a specific number is in:

```
 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
[   0   ][   1   ][   2   ][    3    ]...
```

That's easily done like this:

```
Math.floor(num/3)
```

Here's a quick example:

```js
function range(n) {
  return Math.floor(n / 3);
}

let x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 13, 17, 634]
for(let i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    console.log('Value: ' + x[i] + ', range number: ' + range(x[i]));
}
```

[`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) rounds a value **down** to the nearest integer: `0.2 > 0`, `0.9 > 0`, `1.1 > 1`

Comment: You're very welcome! I take it I correctly understood what you were trying to do then? :-)

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right - I'm very impressed that you understood me because I was in a panic :)

Answer (score 2):

You could divide the value and take the integer of it.

```js
var i;

for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    console.log(i, Math.floor(i / 3));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on

> if values.length == 6 - i have index : 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

and

> then need to get
>
> if 0, 1, 2 - get 0
>
> if 3, 4, 5 - get 1
>
> if 6, 7, 8 - get 2

So you want to return an array for your array in such a that value should increment with index only after a certain number of items.

```
var output = values.map( function( val, index ){ return parseInt( index/3 ) } );
```

Comment: `parseInt` on numbers?

Comment: @Cerbrus yes, it is effectively `Math.floor`

Comment: I know, but why not use `Math.floor`?

Comment: @Cerbrus nothing against `Math.floor`, but it has already been recommended by two experts already.

Comment: So, why post a answer with a non-standard (and semantically incorrect) method?

Comment: @Cerbrus `parseInt` is not non-standard, it is very much part of spec https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-parseint-string-radix

Comment: I mean non-standard as in it's not the method you use to "floor" a number. Just like you don't use a loop to split a string.